# Query last updated posts (posts updated in the last 24 hours)

Tags: loop, wp-query, query-posts, query

I'm having some difficulty to find an example of how to create a loop with posts that had been updated in the last 24 hours.

My idea is to have a page of posts or perhaps on the index.php a lists of posts that had been updated in the last day (24 hours from the time the query is done)

Is this possible ? Is there any way to perform that query ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$timelimit=1 * 86400; //days * seconds per day
$post_age = date('U') - get_post_time('U');
if ($post_age < $timelimit) {
echo 'this post is within my time limits '; //DO SOMETHING
}
?>
```

Comment: Where does this go?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on *where* you want your posts to show, the solution will vary. If you want to filter your main homepage, this solution will do:

```
/**
 * Conditionally add a posts_where filter based on the current query
 *
 * @param object $query
 * @return void
 */
function wpse_53599_24h_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() || ! $query->is_home() )
        return;

    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse_53599_filter_last_24h' );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_53599_24h_pre_get_posts' );

/**
 * Add a clause to posts_where to restrict posts to the last 24h
 *
 * @param string $where
 * @return string
 */
function wpse_53599_filter_last_24h( $where = '' ) {
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '" . date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', time() - DAY_IN_SECONDS ) . "'";
    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse_53599_filter_last_24h' );
    return $where;
}
```

Note that we remove the filter because we don't want to limit *every posts query* run on the site. Only our relevant ones.

If you want to filter a query other than the main home query, just change the conditional within the `pre_get_posts` function.

If you want to filter a sub-query, it's even simpler, just add the `posts_where` filter before your instantiation of WP_Query, and remove it immediately after, and skip the `pre_get_posts` bit.

Comment: Do we change this... DAY_IN_SECONDS?